# AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__' error at kivymd request app

Tags: python, python-requests, kivy, kivymd

it was running while my load file was .kv file but I cant switch screen on condition so I tried string load file but now It show this error.

File "C:\Users\armof\PycharmProjects\screen\main.py", line 142, in logger
payload={'Uname': self.root.ids.user.text, 'psw': self.root.ids.password.text}
File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 864, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.**getattr**
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'

Thanks for your efforts :)

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,ScreenManager
import requests

screen_helper = """
ScreenManager:
    MenuScreen:
    ProfileScreen:
    
<MenuScreen>:
    name : "login"
    Image:
        source:"C:/arka.png"


    MDCard:
        size_hint:None,None
        size: 400,600
        pos_hint : {"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.5}
        elevation:10
        padding:25
        spacing:25
        orientation : 'vertical'
        Image:
            source:"C:/burbantgrilogo.png"
            pos:300,380





        MDLabel:

            text:""
            id:welcome_label
            font_size:30
            halign : 'center'
            size_hint_y:None
            height:self.texture_size[1]
            padding_y:15




        MDTextFieldRound:
            id: user
            hint_text:"username"
            icon_right:"account"
            size_hint_x:None
            width: 200
            font_size:18
            pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5}

        MDTextFieldRound:
            id: password
            hint_text:"password"
            icon_right:"eye-off"
            size_hint_x:None
            width: 200
            font_size:18
            pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5}
            password:True

        MDRoundFlatButton:
            text:"LOG IN"
            font_size: 12
            pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5}
            on_press:app.logger()





        MDRoundFlatButton:
            text:"CLEAR"
            font_size: 12
            pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5}
            on_press:app.clear()

        Widget:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 70
                
<ProfileScreen>:
    name:"Teklif"
    Image:
        source:"C:/arka.png"

    MDCard:
        size_hint:None,None
        size: 400,600
        pos_hint : {"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.5}
        elevation:10
        padding:25
        spacing:25
        orientation : 'vertical'

        Image:
            source:"C:/burbantgrilogo.png"
            pos:300,380




        MDRoundFlatButton:
            text:"OPEN"
            font_size: 12
            pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5}

            on_release: root.current = "login"

        MDRoundFlatButton:
            text:"NEW"
            font_size: 12
            pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5}
        Widget:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 130
            
"""
class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ProfileScreen(Screen):
    pass

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='login'))
sm.add_widget(ProfileScreen(name='Teklif'))

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Red"
        screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        return screen

    def logger(self, *args):


        payload={'Uname': self.root.ids.user.text, 'psw': self.root.ids.password.text}
        print(payload)
        r = requests.get(f"http://burbant.com/otomasyon?Uname={self.root.ids.user.text}&psw={self.root.ids.password.text}")
        print(r.text)

        if r.text == 'True':

            self.root.ids.welcome_label.text = f'Hoşgeldin {self.root.ids.user.text}!'
            sm.switch_to(screen='Teklif')




        else:
            self.root.ids.welcome_label.text = f'Hatalı'
    def clear(self):
        self.root.ids.welcome_label.text = ""
        self.root.ids.user.text = ""
        self.root.ids.password.text = ""


MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `self.root.ids` is an empty dictionary, so trying to access any key in that empty dictionary will cause that error. The `ids` that you are trying to access are in the `MenuScreen` instance, which you can access using the `get_screen()` method of `ScreenManager`, like this:

```
def logger(self, *args):
    menuscreen = self.root.get_screen('login')
    payload = {'Uname': menuscreen.ids.user.text, 'psw': menuscreen.ids.password.text}
    print(payload)
    .
    .
    .
```

You have the same error elsewhere in your code. Wherever you have `self.root.ids`, you will need to apply similar logic.